# How prove $\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+\frac{1}{a_{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}}<2$

Tags: inequality

Let $$A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\}\subset N$$
Suppose that for any two distinct subsets $B, C\subseteq A$, we have
$$\sum_{x\in B}x\neq \sum_{x\in C}x$$

Then show that
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{3}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}<2$$

Comment: Do you mean to say that *any* distinct subsets $B,C\subseteq A$ have different sums?

Comment: @AlexBecker,yes,That's you mean.Thank you

Comment: One possible hint: the condition that $\sum\limits_{x\in B}x\neq\sum\limits_{x\in C}x$ is one way of formalizing the statement that any representable number has a unique representation as a sum of $a_i$.  The 'unique representation' condition is obviously related to binary representation - but there are sequences with $a_i\lt 2a_{i=1}$ for some $i$ that still satisfy the condition (for instance, $A=\{1, 2, 7, 11\}$).  Still, this may be enough to push through a 'weight' argument.

Comment: Potentially helpful:

A has $2^n$ subsets, each of which must have a distinct sum. $\Sigma A$ is the largest such sum, hence is greater than or equal to $2^n-1$.

Comment: Not every question where sets appears is about set theory.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old conjecture of Erdos, which was subsequently proved (Ryavek from my notes) - though I cannot find a handy online reference just now.  The proof goes along the following lines, IIRC:

With $0 < x< 1$, we have by the distinct sum condition:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^{a_k}) < \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac1{1-x} $$

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+x^{a_k}) < - \log (1-x)$$

As both sides are positive, we can divide by $x$ and integrate to get

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 \frac{ \log(1+x^{a_k})}x dx < - \int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x)}x dx $$

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{a_k} \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{ \log(1+t)}t dt < \frac{\pi^2}6 $$
$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{a_k} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{12} < \frac{\pi^2}6 \implies \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{a_k}  < 2 $$

Comment: Here's a paper that proves a generalization of this result and gives some references to the question at hand: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-11/S0002-9939-98-04576-6/S0002-9939-98-04576-6.pdf

Comment: @SteveKass Thanks.  Found another reference with a couple of other ways of proving the same problem: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=RbdP7QG2MyUC&lpg=PA775&ots=bp4Xob85Aj&dq=Canadian%20Mathematical%20Bulletin%20CMB%20volume%2017&pg=PA768#v=onepage&q&f=false